# How to add acknowledgments in the title (first slide) in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, titles, presentations

I am making a beamer presentation, and want to include text for acknowledgments. I use the tags for the title author institute, but now I want to add more text. Is there a tage for the acknowledgements? Is there a nice way to do so? Below is my code which does not compile due to the acknowledgment text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{LOGO}}
\title[Short title of the talk]{cool title}
\author{name1 and name2}
\institute[]
{
University of River, Big City. UK\\
\medskip
{\emph{first.last@bigcity.ac.uk}}
}
\date{\today}
Acknowledgement: This work was performed within the
Mathematics of axiom1, with grant ref.
x12.
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
   \end{frame}
```

Without the text for the acknowledgments, the presentation compiles. What options are available?

Comment: Your acknowledgement text doesn't belong to any command argument. This will not work in the preamble. Either misuse another command and fiddle with the spacing or type the text after the preamble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use some of the already existing commands to add the information; for example, you can say something like

```
\date{\today\\[2em]
{\footnotesize Acknowledgement: This work was performed within the
Mathematics and networks
(molten) project, which is supported by the Engineering
and Physical Sciences Research Council and the Research
Councils UK Digital Economy programme, with grant ref.
EPIxxx.}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me;

To be fair, I only thought to do this because I generally work in LyX and couldn't implement @GonzaloMedina's solution--I tried inserting a footnote & LyX translated it like so:

```
\author{Mr. Indebted%
\thanks{All those lovely people I'm thankful for%
}, et al.}
```

This had the effect (bug?) of singling out the author doing the acknowledging--useful for me because the several authors are on different grants, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the perfect solution, but you can add additional information *after* the preamble and the `\titlepage` command.

```
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 

Acknowledgement: This work was performed … 

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new frame after the finishing title frame.

```
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Acknowledgment}
This work was performed within the
Mathematics of Networks
(molten) project, which is supported by the Engineering
and Physical Sciences Research Council and the Research
Councils UK Digital Economy programme, with grant ref.
EPxxx.
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. To highlight code, you can select the text and click the button marked `{}` above the text field.

Comment: I have understood the question in the way that the acknowledgment should go into the title page additionally.